# How to get column names in result set in Spring data JPA

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have simple procedure which lists out users. I am using `@NamedStoredProcedureQueries` for procedure declaration and used `EntityManager.createNamedStoredProcedureQuery` for `StoredProcedureQuery`.

It returns the result properly but I need column name so that I will know which value is for which column.

My code goes something like this

Entity Class

```
@Entity
@NamedStoredProcedureQueries({ @NamedStoredProcedureQuery(name = 
    "sGetUserList", procedureName = "sGetUserList", parameters = { 
    @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN, name = "user_id", type = 
    Integer.class) }) 
})
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    private String name;

    private String email;

    //getters and setters
}
```

Custom Repositoty

```
public interface UserRepositoryCustom {
    List<?> testProc() ;
}
```

Repository

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long>, 
UserRepositoryCustom{

}
```

Repository Implementation

```
public class UserRepositoryImpl implements UserRepositoryCustom{

    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager em;

    public List<Object> testProc() {

        StoredProcedureQuery q = em.createNamedStoredProcedureQuery("sGetUserList");
        q.setParameter("user_id", 1);
        List<Object> res = q.getResultList();

        return res;
    }
}
```

I need result with column names.

Answer (score 6):

You can get the column names along with their values in a Map. i.e `Map<'column-name', value>`.

```
Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery("{call <<Your procedure>>}");
NativeQueryImpl nativeQuery = (NativeQueryImpl) query;
nativeQuery.setResultTransformer(AliasToEntityMapResultTransformer.INSTANCE);
List<Map<String,Object>> result = nativeQuery.getResultList();
```

This will be very helpful in a places where you want to use column names as a placeholder in HTML where value will replace it in runtime.

Comment: any hint on how to handle the random order of the column names?

Answer (score 4):

Here , I have written a method from you can get JSON from you can get key value pair of column and value

```
@Transactional
@Component
public class CustomRepository<T> {

    @Autowired
    private EntityManager em;

    private ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    public List<T> getResultOfQuery(String argQueryString,Class<T> valueType) {
        try {
            Query query = em.createNativeQuery(argQueryString);
            NativeQueryImpl nativeQuery = (NativeQueryImpl) query;
            nativeQuery.setResultTransformer(AliasToEntityMapResultTransformer.INSTANCE);
            List<Map<String,Object>> result = nativeQuery.getResultList();
            List<T> resultList = result.stream()
                    .map(o -> {
                        try {
                            return mapper.readValue(mapper.writeValueAsString(o),valueType);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            ApplicationLogger.logger.error(e.getMessage(),e);
                        }
                        return null;
                    }).collect(Collectors.toList());
            return resultList;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ApplicationLogger.logger.error(ex.getMessage(),ex);
            throw ex;
        }
    }
}
```

The Only condition is that your query and pojo attribute name should be same

Comment: God Bless You Man ! You Saved Me . Thanks Alot

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to do here. If you want to get all the users using Spring data you shouldn't be implementing your UserRepository. Spring Data does this for you.

In fact the JpaRepository already has the method you need.

```
List<User> findAll();
```

You can just call this to get a list of all your users and won't need to worry about the column names.

Just inject your repository where you need it and call the method to get all users:

```
@Autowire
UserRepository userRepository;

List<Users> allUsers = userRepository.findAll();
```

EDIT: If there is a particular reason you want to use stored procedures though there is a Spring Data way of doing this without implementing UserRepository yourself. You can do this by defining the following method:

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long>{
   @Procedure(name = "sGetUserList")
   List<User> sGetUserList(@Param("user_id") Integer userId);

}
```

Again there shouldn't be any issue with resolving column names with this method.

Comment: In this case it is ok but what if i have some procedure which does some analysis and gives the result and that result set does not have any model. How would i do that ? For example if i write a procedure which gives me the list of users with count of logins in a day. It has count column which i have not defined anywhere. This is just one example, i have so many analysis procedure something like this. How to overcome this situation?

Comment: Ok that is a more difficult situation. From what I understand if you want column names for a non-defined entity you would be better off using JDBC over Spring Data. To do this in spring data you would have to define @Entities that have properties which match your expected result set columns and put the `@NamedStoredProcedureQueries` annotations on those.

Comment: @Plog can I do the same process to get column names of a table?or the process is different to retrieve from tables of a database?

Answer (score 0):

To maintain the column name order, you can build your own `AliasedTupleSubsetResultTransformer` with `LinkedHashMap` like:

```
public class AliasToEntityLinkedHashMapResultTransformer extends AliasedTupleSubsetResultTransformer {

    public static final AliasToEntityLinkedHashMapResultTransformer INSTANCE = new AliasToEntityLinkedHashMapResultTransformer();

    @Override
    public Object transformTuple(Object[] tuple, String[] aliases) {
        LinkedHashMap result = new LinkedHashMap(tuple.length);

        for (int i = 0; i < tuple.length; i++) {
            String alias = aliases[i];
            if (alias != null) {
                result.put(alias, tuple[i]);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isTransformedValueATupleElement(String[] aliases, int tupleLength) {
        return false;
    }

    private Object readResolve() {
        return INSTANCE;
    }
}
```

and use it in:

```
nativeQuery.setResultTransformer(AliasToEntityLinkedHashMapResultTransformer.INSTANCE);
```